# Grouping filter on Pandas

Tags: pandas

i was trying to apply filter on grouping function, but i am not getting right syntax. Typically the way we apply filter on grouping function in SQL, i am looking for the same feature or functionality in Pandas.
This is my query, and i want to filter the result where count>=5
home.groupby('location').agg({'price_per_sqft':['mean','std','count']})

[image: Result of above query]

Could you show me the way to filter the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First for avoid `MultiIndex` add column `price_per_sqft` after `groupby` and then filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = home.groupby('location')['price_per_sqft'].agg(['mean','std','count'])
df1 = df[df['count']>=5]
```

Or [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df1 = df.query("count>=5")
```

Another idea is used named aggregations:

```
df = home.groupby('location').agg(avg=('price_per_sqft', 'mean'),
                                  std=('price_per_sqft', 'std'),
                                  counts=('price_per_sqft', 'count'))
df1 = df[df['counts']>=5]
```